# gcc linker finding both .so and .a in the library path which is chosen?

Tags: gcc, linker

If I run

```
gcc a.c -L /usr/lib -lexpat
```

and both libexpat.a and libexpat.so are in /usr lib which one is used by the linker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the shared library (.so) will be chosen.

If you want to change this behavior, `-static` gcc option may be used

> -static
>
> On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking
>   with the shared libraries. On other
>   systems, this option has no effect.