# g++ library search failure

Tags: gcc, linker, g++

I have a directory structure as below:

```
/
|
+--- /lib
|      libsomething.a
|      libsomething.so
|
+----/obj
       anObjFile.o
```

When I run the following command from within the `obj` directory:

`g++  -L../lib -lsomething anObjFile.o`

I get `undefined reference` errors. Apparently `gcc` is failing to locate `libsomething.a`.

But now if I delete `libsomething.so` and then rerun the command, linking succeeds.

As per [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) `-lsomething` should expand to `libsomething.a`. Then why is  presence of `libsomething.so` causing the library search to fail? Also, how can I resolve this problem?

I'm on Linux Mint 12 with `gcc` version 4.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .so file is a dynamic library, meaning it is used each time you run your program. In that case you need to tell your OS (Mint in this case) where that dynamic library is located so your prgramm can find it at run time.

The .a file is a static library, meaning functions needed from it will be copied into your prgramm while linking. So your prgramm can run without the library file.

If nothing else is said gcc will assume you want to use the dynamic lib. If it can find a .so file it will use it instead of a .a file. If you want to tell gcc to make your programm static (use the .a file) you can add -static to your gcc call.

However the reason why the linking fails when the dynamic library is used is not clear. How did you install/build the library?

Comment: Haatschii, I have a question: shouldn't the invocation "g++ -L../lib -lsomething anObjFile.o" force g++ to link to the static lib 'libsomething.a'? The gcc documentation clearly says that '-lsomething' expands to 'libsomething.a', not 'libsomething.so'. Or, does the presence of 'libsomething.so' (the dynamic lib) makes g++ prefer it even in the case of the above invocation?

Comment: My question in the above comment is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545907/gcc-linker-finding-both-so-and-a-in-the-library-path-which-is-chosen. You're right Haatschii, 'libsomething.so' is being chosen here. Now, as you say, there seems to be a problem with 'libsomething.so'. I'm gonna go investigate that. Thanks for your answer :-)